# Javascript Onclick event error: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to add some input fields when an onclick event occurs. I'm using javascript to get this done. When i was trying in fiddle it worked well. But it does not work on my localhost. I'm getting below error message.

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
$(".more").click(function() {
```

And here are my codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE script PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <script src="//admin/lib/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript">
      </script>

      <link href="//admin/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(".more").click(function() {
        $("#container").append("<br><div id='test'><label>Title: </label><input type=\"text\" id=\"txt_jobTitle\">&nbsp;<label>Company</label><input type=\"text\" id=\"id2\">&nbsp;<label>Started</label><input type=\"text\" id=\"txt_jobStarted\">&nbsp;<label>Ended</label><input type=\"text\" id=\"txt_jobStarted\">&nbsp;<div class='box'><a href='#'>x</a></div></div><br/>");
        var count = $(".box").length;

    });

        $(".box a").live("click", function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
            $("#test").remove();
        });

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>


        <div id="container">

                                <a href="#" class="more">Add more +</a>
                        </div>

    </body>

        </html>
```

I have no idea how could i sort this issue out since i'm not key player in javascript. How can i solve this issue?

I came across many similar solutions with same issue but none of them worked out.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<script src="//admin/lib/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` Try to access that file manually, are you sure it's there and it works?

Comment: Make sure you've given correct path for jquery

Comment: As an aside, you might wish to correct the `DOCTYPE` string to use `html`, not `script`. A faulty `DOCTYPE` string puts browsers into Quirks Mode.

Comment: Okay, now i'm referring to a google jquery. The error was dissapeared but i'm getting another error now. TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
 

$(".box a").live("click", function() {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you are using correct path for jquery , try load it externaly like rajesh said ,

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

and if you load externally jquery `1.10.1` there will be a problem , your `live` function will not work .

```
    $(".box a").live("click", function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $("#test").remove();
    });
```

so make it `on()`

```
$(document).on("click",".box a", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $("#test").remove();
});
```

here is fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kanishka_bandara/pVRL3/

Comment: Previous issue was solved. I'm getting a new error now. TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
 

$(".box a").live("click", function() {

Comment: @FawzanIzy , hi try my code , i have mentioned it in my answer

Comment: use $(document).on("click",".box a", function() { instead of -> $(".box a").live("click", function() {

Comment: Well i changed. I do not see any error messages. But my result is null. I'm not getting any results when i click on it. any reasons?

Comment: @FawzanIzy  have you checked http://jsfiddle.net/kanishka_bandara/pVRL3/ , it is working very nicely here

Comment: Well i know it works perfectly on fiddle. When i was trying on fiddle it worked well. Prob is my local i guess. Btw ur name sounds so sri lankan.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36240/discussion-between-kanishka-panamaldeniya-and-fawzan-izy)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your code is called before the `jQuery` library is included, or the path to the `jQuery` js file is wrong/incorrect.

Comment: Okay. I added google jquery. The previous error was disappeared. But i'm getting a new error.  TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
$(".box a").live("click", function() {

Answer (score 0):

Try with `jQuery` instead `$` like

```
jQuery(".more").click(function() {        
    //Do whatever
});
```

And makesure that you have loaded the `js` library file like `jquery-1.10.2.js` And put the script in `DOM ready`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `jQuery.noConflict()` because your `jQuery library` is conflicting with other library which also use `$`

And also wrap code inside `document.ready`

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict(). Old references of $ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict() simply restores them.

[**Official Document**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: What might the other library be in this case? I see no other libraries used in the sample document included in the question.

Comment: I don't think its conflicting with any other since i use only one library. If i have not misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

try this if it work than you jquery js path is not correct

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, I used this code instead of calling the internal library. Now i'm getting another error. TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
 

$(".box a").live("click", function() {

Comment: becoz live (http://api.jquery.com/live/) is removed in 1.9 so use ON instead  (http://api.jquery.com/on/)